# select dropdown from options when options are in separate tags

Tags: drop-down-menu, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am a beginner in using webdriver  and Here is the code with which i am working.
I want to click on a dropdown and again click on the list of values provided for that dropdown.
Please help me, i looked for other threads, but they are different.

```
<ul>
  <li class="size select required">
    <div id="dk_container_partNumber-55414" class="dk_container dk_theme_size dk_focus"
    tabindex="" style="display: block;">
      <a class="dk_toggle" style="width: 162px;">
        <div class="dk_options">
          <ul class="dk_options_inner">
            <li class="dk_option_current">
              <li class="">
                <a data-dk-dropdown-value="605930243">S</a>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                <a data-dk-dropdown-value="605930251">M</a>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                <a data-dk-dropdown-value="605930260">L</a>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                <a data-dk-dropdown-value="605930278">XL</a>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                <a data-dk-dropdown-value="605930286">XXL</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <select id="partNumber-55414" class="size-select" name="partNumber" style="display: none;">
      <option data-property="CAT_SELECTSIZE" selected="selected" value="">Select Size</option>
      <option value="605930243">S</option>
      <option value="605930251">M</option>
      <option value="605930260">L</option>
      <option value="605930278">XL</option>
      <option value="605930286">XXL</option>
    </select>
```

I wish to select "S" and the same must be seen on the dropdown.
I am able to click on the dropdown and see the list of options using the below code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//(more xpath goes here)/ul/li[@class = 'size select required']/div/a/span")).click();
```

I tried the below code to select "S", but in vain :

```
Select SizeDropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//(more xpath  here)/ul/li[@class = 'size select required']/select")));
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//(more xpath here)/ul/li[@class = 'size select required']/select)/option[2]")).click();
//Below line gets and clicks the first option of Select Size 'S'
//SizeDropdown.getFirstSelectedOption().click();
//SizeDropdown.selectByVisibleText("S");
//SizeDropdown.selectByIndex(1);
//SizeDropdown.selectByValue("S");
```

I tried each command separately (after uncommenting),but could not see the "S" as the label of the dropdown as if it is selected by me.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want to do. Maybe make a jsfiddle.

Comment: And you may want to re-tag your question appropriately.

Comment: @Wivlaro -- i dont know how to make a jsfiddle, i posted the code i see for the webpage and also the webdriver code that i tried,i want to select the size as "S". Is it clear now??

Comment: Coulnd't fully understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simplifying your xpath?

I use something like this to select an option from a drop down *without* first clicking to expand it:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='partNumber-55414']"));
select.selectByVisibleText("S");
```